# Spring Boot Actuator + Kubernetes + Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, keycloak

Firstly, let me give you some info about the app:

I have some Spring Boot services backed by `Keycloak` for authentication/authorization. The app is going to be deployed on kubernetes. I want to add `Spring Boot Actuator` to all of my Spring Boot apps to have health checks/monitoring capabilities.

When deployed to a k8s environment, actuator gives `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` endpoints out-of-the-box, see [this blog post](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-kubernetes-probes). I want all actuator endpoints to be secured by keycloak. That means that k8s would hit 401s when attempting to fetch status for my probes. How could I tackle with this ?

I have some solutions that could work:

- Retrieve a bearer token with `curl` and put it as a header in `httpGet` (too slow in my opinion).
- Restrict `/actuator` in ingress so that external users cannot access the endpoints and let endpoints unsecured (better but not an ideal solution).

But I'm almost certain that there has to be a better way. Any ideas ?

Comment: what's the problemi with the second one? restricting the access on a specific network/subnet should not cause any problem

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Endpoints would be internally insecure. Only certain users/service accounts must have access to these endpoints.